# How can you detect if a user replied to a message of a bot in discord.js?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I have searched the discord.js documentation but I can't find a way to make the bot detect if their own messages were replied by a user in a discord server. Is there a way to do this?

Thank you so much,
Paul10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All messages have a `message_reference` property. This contains the guild, channel and message id. This property is null if it isn’t a reply. I assume you already know the channel.

```js
//async function
//message is an instance of Message
let { channel, message_reference: reply } = message
const repliedTo = await channel.messages.fetch(reply.message_id);
//repliedTo is now the replied message with author, content, etc
```

Comment: For Discord.js V13 it is not `message_reference` anymore. It's has been renamed to `reference`. `message_id` has also been changed to `messageId`