# Check if someone replies to a bot in discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm making a discord bot for asking people questions. How do I check if a certain user replies to it? (User A will say "!ask @UserB" and Bot will say "@UserB, Please answer the question" and UserB will reply.) I know the general code works, but I need a way to check for replies and the content of them.

Code:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'ask',
    description: 'asks a question',
    async execute(message, args) {
        if (!args[0]) {
            message.reply("Specify User");
        } else {
            message.channel.send(args[0] + " Please answer the question."); // args[0] will be the user
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All messages have a `message_reference` property. This contains the guild, channel and message id. This property is null if it isn’t a reply. I assume you already know the channel.

```js
//async function
//message is an instance of Message
let { channel, message_reference: reply } = message
const repliedTo = await channel.messages.fetch(reply.message_id);
//repliedTo is now the replied message with author, content, etc
if(repliedTo.author.bot) {
//replied messages author is a bot
}
```

Copied from my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68717484/15781079)